# simple search bar in ionic not filtering

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So basically, i have a web application that filters a location. My code is running without errors but why is it not filtering? been debugging for hours but i cant seem to figure the error please help me.

this is my code in home.html

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
<ion-title>
  Ionic Blank
  </ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-searchbar (ionIput)="getTopics($event)"></ion-searchbar> 

<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let topic of topics">
    {{ topic }}
</ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

this is the code in home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.generateTopics();
 }

topics: string[];

    generateTopics(){
this.topics = [
'Dumaguete city',
'bacong february 1 2018',
'Dumaguete february 2 2018',
'Sibulan february 3 2018',
'bacong february 4 2018',
'ajong february 5 2018',
'dauin february 6 2018',
'zamboanguita february 7 2018',
];
}


    getTopics(ev: any) {
this.generateTopics();
let serVal = ev.target.value;
if( serVal && serVal.trim() != ''){
    this.topics == this.topics.filter((topic) =>{
        return (topic.toLowerCase().indexOf(serVal.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using compare operator instead of assignment operator.
Use this

```
getTopics(ev: any) {
    this.generateTopics();
    let serVal = ev.target.value;
    if (serVal && serVal.trim() != '') {
      this.topics = this.topics.filter((topic) => { //here you used == instead of =
        return (topic.toLowerCase().indexOf(serVal.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result back to the variable, not compare. Also you can simplify the filer as

```
this.topics = this.topics.filter(t=>t.toLowerCase().indexOf(serVal.toLowerCase()) > -1);
```